# How to ALTER the Table Value Parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, table-valued-parameters

I am not getting option like 'ALTER TO' when am right clicking on TVP

Comment: ALTER TO for TVP?? a TVP is part of a function / procedure definition. Not an entity by itself!?

Comment: ALTER TO option is not enabled RT ?

Comment: Table-valued parameters are a new parameter type in SQL Server 2008. Table-valued parameters are declared by using user-defined table types. I guess you are asking about ALTERing user-defined table type?? As far as I know, you can CREATE and DROP a user-defined table type, but not ALTER it.

Answer (score 46):

Can't do it. You must drop/recreate. If you have dependencies on the TVP, you must:

1. create new TVP under new name
2. alter dependencies to use (1)
3. drop old TVP
4. recreate (1) under original name
5. alter dependencies to use (4)
6. drop (1)

Comment: Thank you, but the hassle sucks.

Comment: Why do you have to use a new name?

Comment: You can't have two types with the same name, and you can't drop the old type if it's being referenced by another object. If you don't mind dropping all the referencing objects first, and then dropping the type, then you can recreate it using the same name directly, and not go through this dance. But if you cannot afford to drop referencing objects first, because you cannot afford any downtime, then you must go through this dance.

Answer (score 16):

I've found a [blog post on sqltreeo.com](http://www.sqltreeo.com/wp/scripting-dependecies-of-user-defined-table-types/) which has a way to automate the process by temporary dropping the dependencies and then re-creating them.

I just modified it a bit.

1.You should create the following procedure:

```
-- Find all referencing objects to user-defined table type in @fullObjectName parameter
-- and generate DROP scripts and CREATE scripts for them
CREATE PROC [dbo].[alterTableType] (@fullObjectName VARCHAR(200))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF (TYPE_ID (@fullObjectName) IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('User-defined table type ''%s'' does not exists. Include full object name with schema.', 16,1, @fullObjectName)
        RETURN
    END;

    WITH sources
    AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME(m.object_id)) RowId, definition
        FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies d
        JOIN sys.sql_modules m ON m.object_id = d.referencing_id
        JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id = m.object_id
        WHERE referenced_id = TYPE_ID(@fullObjectName)
    )
    SELECT 'BEGIN TRANSACTION'
    UNION ALL   
    SELECT 

        'DROP ' +
            CASE OBJECTPROPERTY(referencing_id, 'IsProcedure')
            WHEN 1 THEN 'PROC '
            ELSE
                CASE
                    WHEN OBJECTPROPERTY(referencing_id, 'IsScalarFunction') = 1 OR OBJECTPROPERTY(referencing_id, 'IsTableFunction') = 1 OR OBJECTPROPERTY(referencing_id, 'IsInlineFunction') = 1 THEN 'FUNCTION '
                    ELSE ''
                END
            END
        + SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) + '.' +
        + OBJECT_NAME(m.object_id)    

    FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies d
    JOIN sys.sql_modules m ON m.object_id = d.referencing_id
    JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id = m.object_id
    WHERE referenced_id = TYPE_ID(@fullObjectName)
    UNION  ALL
    SELECT  'GO'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '---- WRITE HERE SCRIPT TO DROP OLD USER DEFINED TABLE TYPE AND CREATE A NEW ONE ----' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    UNION  ALL
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN number = RowId    THEN DEFINITION
            ELSE 'GO'
        END
     FROM sources s
    JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT number FROM master.dbo.spt_values) n ON n.number BETWEEN RowId AND RowId+1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'COMMIT'
END
```

2.Then you should run it with your table type name as a input parameter. Show the results on grid format (because text format might truncate long texts), select entire result table and copy it to a new query window.

Comment: The Row with the Create seems to be missing CR+LF's.  When I Pasted it into a new Query Window or a text editor, it Pasted as one big line.  I was using SSMS 2016 running on SS 2008 R2.

Comment: See this answer to make SSMS grid results retain CR/LF on copy https://stackoverflow.com/a/37284582/3055415

Comment: Brilliant tool - CR+LF's. was an issue, but this saved a lot of time

Answer (score 3):

#### Problem

You cannot drop the User Defined Table Type as long as it's referenced by anything else:

> Cannot drop type '*dbo.MyTableType*' because it is being referenced by object '*MyStoredProcedure*'. There may be other objects that reference this type.

It would be nice if SSMS gave you a listing of all other objects, but if you don't have many, a partially manual approach might work fine.

#### Find Usages

To get a list of all SPs that use your TVP type, you can query `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`

```sql
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(d.referencing_id)
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies d
WHERE d.referenced_id = TYPE_ID('MyTableType')
```

#### Steps

1. Select all SPs identified above and select `DROP and CREATE to` new window
2. Go through each window, and just highlight / execute the `DROP PROCEDURE` section
3. Now you can select your type and select `DROP and CREATE to` new window and make any changes
4. Go back to the list of SP's windows you opened and execute the `CREATE` section

#### Further Reading

- [Altering user-defined table types in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11410722/1366033)
- [How to do ALTER TABLE TYPE efficiently](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/196482/31340)
- [List user defined types in a SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54496/1366033)

Answer (score 0):

1. Drop all the SP's which uses the TVP you want to alter.(Don't Forget to get the backup the of SP's & TVP)
2. Now Drop the TVP Which you have to alter.
3. Than Modify the same TVP which you have dropped in step 2 & than Create it Again.(TVP is altered here).
4. Now Create again all the SP's Which you have dropped in 1st Step. (Your SP's are ready to use with altered TVP).

You will get back the TVP and All the Sp's which uses the same TVP.