# SSMS Results to Grid - CRLF not preserved in copy/paste - any better techniques?

Tags: sql-server, formatting, ssms

When I have a result set in the grid like:

```
SELECT 'line 1
line 2
line 3'
```

or

```
SELECT 'line 1' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'line 2' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'line 3'
```

With embedded CRLF, the display in the grid appears to replace them with spaces (I guess so that they will display all the data).

The problem is that if I am code-generating a script, I cannot simply cut and paste this.  I have to convert the code to open a cursor and print the relevant columns so that I can copy and paste them from the text results.

Is there any simpler workaround to preserve the CRLF in a copy/paste operation from the results grid?

The reason that the grid is helpful is that I am currently generating a number of scripts for the same object in different columns - a bcp out in one column, an xml format file in another, a table create script in another, etc...

Answer (score 167):

This issue has been fixed in [SSMS 16.5 build 13.0.16000.28](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt238290.aspx) with the addition of an option to preserve CR/LF on copy/save ([more details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms190078.aspx#Anchor_0)) ([Connect bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/735714)).

1. **Tools > Options**
2. Expand **Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Grid**
3. Tick **Retain CR/LF on copy or save**
4. Restart SSMS

This will cause `CR`, `LF`, and `CRLF` to be treated as newlines when you copy a cell.

Comment: One more sidenote: I had to restart SSMS after selecting this option before it started working.

Comment: This would have saved me hours if I had seen it sooner. I assumed the SSIS package was stripping out my line breaks.

I also had to restart SSMS before this change took effect.

Comment: For me the changed setting already affected a new query window. No need to restart SSMS.

Comment: why is this not on by default??

Comment: Did not have to restart SSMS but did have to close Query Editor window and open a new Query Editor window.

Comment: Did have to restart SSMS, as closing the Query Editor window and opening a new Query Editor window did not pick up the change.

Answer (score 14):

Answering this for myself because I can never remember where this is:

[image]

Comment: A mnemonic based on the acronym for Tools Options Queue (Results) S(ql server) R(esults to) Grid:
The Optimal Quest Should Return Gold

Comment: A restart of SSMS is needed for this to take effect. (This is mentioned elsewhere, but should be in this answer for good measure)

Answer (score 2):

Warning: There's definitely some kind of bug still with this feature.

First of all, I haven't touched the option in months and have recently rebooted.

I had a query with several columns, one of which contained customer feedback (with linefeeds). When I pasted the results into Google Docs / Excel the feedback went into one line (as I wanted).

I then copied the query to another file and ran it again. This time the results contained line breaks!

So either there is a very odd bug, or some secret shortcut that changes the setting for the current window. Interested if anyone else sees this behavior.

Answer (score -3):

it is a hack, but try this:

wrap your result set in a REPLACE (.....,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),CHAR(182)) to preserve the line breaks, you can then replace them back

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE ('line 1' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)+ 'line 2' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'line 3'
            ,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),CHAR(182)
            )
```

OUTPUT:

```
----------------------
line 1¶line 2¶line 3

(1 row(s) affected)
```

replace them back in SQL:

```
select replace('line 1¶line 2¶line 3',CHAR(182),CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))
```

output:

```
-------------------
line 1
line 2
line 3

(1 row(s) affected)
```

or in a good text editor.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but this isn't any less work than selecting a single column at a time in text output mode or doing the print with a cursor.

Answer (score -4):

One thing you can do is send results to a file, then use an editor capable of watching a file for changes which has superior capabilities for understanding the output.