# How to store "new line" in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, newline

I want to use new line in my select query

For example:

```
SELECT
    FULLNAME + ADDRESS AS X1
FROM 
    TBL_USERS
```

and the result should be something like this:

```
ABBAS KOLAHDOOZAN
ISFAHAN,BOZORGMEHR ST
```

as a single column.

I use `CHAR(10), CHAR(13)` but that dont work.

Does anyone have a working solution?

Comment: You need to expand on 'dont work'

Answer (score 5):

The Sql

```
SELECT
 FULLNAME + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ADDRESS AS X1
FROM
TBL_USERS;
```

Will insert a Windows CRLF between the columns. What you might be seeing is SSMS's Output to Grid results, which will [eat whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679481/ssms-results-to-grid-crlf-not-preserved-in-copy-paste-any-better-techniques). Switch to Text results mode if you want to see the actual result.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(MAX)= 'ABBAS KOLAHDOOZAN'
DECLARE @town VARCHAR(MAX)= 'ISFAHAN,BOZORGMEHR ST'
DECLARE @NewLineChar AS CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

PRINT( @name + @NewLineChar + @town)
```

Comment: i want to select no print

Comment: SSMS will display it in a single line if you have the output showing in a grid. If you change the output to text it will display multiple lines.  (Ctrl+T = Results to Text
Ctrl+D = Results to Grid)