# Inconsistent SQL Server Management Studio results regarding CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a problem with consistency on different SQL Server versions. With the following code:

```
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(50)
SET @text = 'This is line 1.' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 'This is line 2.'
SELECT @text
```

I copy and paste results into notepad

From SQL Server 2008R2 shows

> This is line 1.  This is line 2.

From SQL Server 2014 shows

> This is line 1.
>   This is line 2.

Any idea how I can fix this? Or why it is like this? I want to achieve the latter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `PRINT` instead of `SELECT`.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no solution to this for select statements in SQL Server 2008. It was fixed in later versions though (from 2012, the "bug" doesn't exist. In 2016 I believe it's off by default but can be adjusted by going to Options -> Query Results -> SQL Server -> Results to Grid -> Retain CR/LF... This isn't necessary in 2012/2014 and there's no backwards compatibility for 2008). I tried this in SQL 2008 and a quick look at the hex of the output when selecting @text shows the carriage return/line feed are replaced by spaces.

Comment: Here's a different stack overflow thread on the issue (from 2010 so presumably using SQL 2008): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679481/ssms-results-to-grid-crlf-not-preserved-in-copy-paste-any-better-techniques - I haven't tried anything in the marked answer but you might find an idea there that works.

Comment: @ZLK thank you, I suppose I could just use the newer management studio :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried in sql server 2008 R2(SP2). It does not have the issue you specified.

Also a tip is that you can change the results to show in Text, as opposed to Grid, so you can see the output easily without having to copy and paste.

Naz