# Append a New Line onto each concatenated row from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following sql query correctly concatenates each row of the table for a given foreign key `PlanId`. However, The `CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)` appear to be ignored.

```
SELECT PlanID,
   STUFF(
            (
                SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CONVERT(DATE, CreateTimestamp)) + ' ' + CreateUserID + ': ' + Notes
                       + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
                FROM PlanNotes
                WHERE PlanID = OuterNotes.PlanId
                ORDER BY UpdateTimestamp DESC
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),
            1,
            0,
            ''
        ) AS Notes
FROM PlanNotes OuterNotes;
```

The resulting output looks like:

> 2017-12-04 nickh: Nick's Test Notes v2  2017-11-27 bobj: Original date was 6/1/2016.

When I want:

> 2017-12-04 nickh: Nick's Test Notes v2
>   2017-11-27 bobj: Original date was

Comment: perhaps this link can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057/how-to-insert-a-line-break-in-a-sql-server-varchar-nvarchar-string

Comment: in the select query, you will not find the result, if you loop on the result and you use `print` , you will find that the newline is already there, now depends on how you are consuming the result for example, rendering in html or text or a `usercontrol` like `datagrid`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37284582/73226

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the `CHAR(10)` and `CHAR(13)` characters did in fact make it into your output, but that for whatever reason SSMS or your particular tool is not rendering them as you would expect.  A workaround here might be to output your query to a text file and then open in a bona-fide text editor (e.g. Notepad++).

Comment: I dropped the output to text and it seems to be behaving as I'd expect. *Shakes fist at SSMS* Thank you!