# Line Break issues while copying data from result to new query in Sql Sever 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, line-breaks

I am trying to copy the result which is a query and trying to indent it the way it should be. But when I copy and paste it in the new window, the query displays in 1 single line instead of multiple lines.  I am trying to get it working on sql server 2008.

Here is a sample of my code. It is a stored procedure that is a result.

```
Create procedure dbo.test @Mypath  nvarchar(max) AS BEGIN Declare @iterator int set @iterator=1 .....
```

What I want when I copy and paste is

```
 Create procedure dbo.test @Mypath nvarchar(max) 
 AS 
 BEGIN

 Declare @iterator int 
set @iterator=1
```

The code is around 1000 lines hence, entering new line is a big task.

Therefore I need a setting that when I copy and paste my result procedure it should display as a procedure in multiple lines .

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not clear, at first you say _result_ but it seems like you want to format the code, **not the result**. I don't understand, are looking for a tool to format the code?

Comment: What is your result a result of?

Comment: Well, I say result because I use SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID(N'test.dbo')); to get the stored proc as a result. And hence when I copy and paste the result of this query to another window, it displays the query in 1 single line instead of multiple lines.

Comment: Do you have to get the stored proc that way, or can you right-click and script it?

Comment: I have to get it that way, since it is in a recovery mode. I cannot directly right click and script it, which would have been way easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but since it still comes up in searches, please refer to:

[SSMS Results to Grid - CRLF not preserved in copy/paste - any better techniques?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679481/ssms-results-to-grid-crlf-not-preserved-in-copy-paste-any-better-techniques)

or

[image]