# I would like to add a new line in SELECT statement in SSMS. how can it be done?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to add a new line in SELECT statement in SSMS. how can it be done? 
I wanted to display the output as

```
No columnname
---------
1
2
```

I tried

```
select '1'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'2'
```

It showing the o/ p as

No

```
columnname
---------
1 2
```

But did not help..

Please advice

Comment: it is coming as 1 2 .Please explain your problem well

Comment: SSMS doesn't matter as much as the output of your application. What are you trying to do with this data? Is it for a report, or do you just want to see a new line there?

Comment: This also contains some useful information:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679481/ssms-results-to-grid-crlf-not-preserved-in-copy-paste-any-better-techniques

Comment: Yes its for a report.. that comes in the top of the report.I pass static data  and the second set of data has to be in the second line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
select v 
from ( values (1), (2), (3)
     ) val(v)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method of `select '1'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'2'` was correct... you simply need to change the results to text instead of grid. It's a button on the toolbar. In Grid mode, this is still one row, thus it's in the first row.

It's the left button in these three:

[image: Results]

[image: SSMS Example]

Answer (score 0):

This would be work with `print` command or you can also copy the whole text & pase into notepad to see desired result.

```
print '1'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'2'
```