# SQL Server: removing line breaks when exporting data to csv file using Bulk export utility

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bulk

I have a table which I need to export to a csv file. This table has an xml field which can have line breaks that I must remove.
I am using the [bcp utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017) to export data from Sql Server to the csv file.

This is the strucutre of the table:

```
ID int
CODE varchar(20)
XML_DATA xml
```

This is the command I am using:

```
bcp "SELECT ID, CODE, replace(convert(nvarchar(max), XML_DATA), CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), ' ') as XML_DATA FROM MYDB.dbo.MyTable" queryout C:\output.csv -c -t0x1F -T -S "10.10.10.28"
```

For some reasons the output file still contains the line breaks. But if I run the same query on SQL Server for a record which has a line break, the output is correct (line breaks removed):

```
SELECT
    ID, 
    CODE, 
    replace(convert(nvarchar(max), XML_DATA), CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), ' ') as XML_DATA
FROM MYDB.dbo.MyTable
WHERE ID = 1099; -- record with a line break in the XML_DATA field
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It may be that your xml contains CHAR(10) + CHAR(13), not CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), and when you run the query in SSMS you don't see that line breake is still there because you may output to grid, you should output to Text instead

Comment: @sepupic Yep I was writing exactly that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Solved replacing this line

```
replace(convert(nvarchar(max), XML_DATA), CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), ' ') as XML_DATA
```

with this

```
replace(replace(convert(nvarchar(max), XML_DATA), CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ') as XML_DATA
```

Also I would like to point out that Sql Server Management Studio by default does not include CLRF characters on copy/paste from a query result, you must explicitly enable an option to preserve CLRF characters and restart SQL Server: [preverse CLRF on Sql Server Management Studio query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679481/ssms-results-to-grid-crlf-not-preserved-in-copy-paste-any-better-techniques). That was giving me some confusion ^_^

Comment: >>>you must explicitly enable an option to preserve CLRF characters<<< As already mentioned in comment, you can simply ouput to text instead of a grid, you can find this button on a toolbar in SSMS next to execution plan button, there are 3 similar buttons with an arrow that put data to text(you'll see rows on the picture), to grid(default choice), to file (blank sheet)