# Options for SQL formatting that deal with comments in single line queries pulled from DMV's

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, formatter

I am a DBA and thus I grab a lot of query text out of various dmv's to inspect the problem queries. I use Poor Man T-SQL formatter currently. The issue I have is when pulling query text from a dmv like this code chunk:

SQL server version 2012 or above btw.

```
SELECT P.spid,
    P.STATUS,
    P.hostname,
    P.loginame,
    P.cpu,
    R.start_time,
    R.command,
    P.program_name,
    TEXT
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests R
CROSS JOIN master.dbo.sysprocesses P
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(P.sql_handle)
WHERE 1 = 1 
    and P.STATUS NOT IN ('sleeping', 'background')
    AND R.session_id = P.spid
    AND P.spid <> @@spid --ignore this query
```

When I grab a value from the TEXT column and paste to a new window I often end up with terrible adhoc queries where it looks something like this nonsensical query i just wrote

```
SELECT X, Y --OPTIONAL, Z FROM ALPHABET as abc --FOR SPECIAL CASES LEFT JOIN AGGREGATECOUNT as A ON A.id = abc.id where 4>3 --to deal with non english AND 1=1
```

when formatting with the tools I have tried such as poorman t-sql formattor I cannot get this out of its 'single line' state without manually skipping over the comments. Is there any formatter (plugin for ssms or notepad++ is a plus.) that handles this situation? or should I be pulling the text out differently to avoid this problem of all the newlines missing?  For example formatting the above with my tools yields

```
SELECT 
     X
    ,Y --OPTIONAL, Z FROM ALPHABET as abc --FOR SPECIAL CASES LEFT JOIN AGGREGATECOUNT as A ON A.id = abc.id where 4>3 --to deal with non english AND 1=1
```

If no good tool exists, any tips to improve my current process that involves manually adding a new line after "obvious" comments?

What I'm aiming for:

```
SELECT 
     X
    ,Y --OPTIONAL
    , Z 
FROM ALPHABET as abc 
--FOR SPECIAL CASES 
LEFT JOIN AGGREGATECOUNT as A ON A.id = abc.id 
WHERE 4>3 
--to deal with non english
AND 1=1
```

Comment: Do you have the option "Retain CR/LF on copy or save" enabled? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37284582/73226. Not sure if the DMVs are stripping them out or SSMS

Comment: I do not, thank you so much for giving me that link. problem solved. if you post an answer ill list yours as accepted incase anyone else comes looking for the problem with similar wording to my post

Comment: closing as dupe will have same effect.

Comment: thank you, this will be helping me so much at work :)