# How to retain new line character in JSON_VALUE SQL server

Tags: json, sql-server

How to retain new line character in JSON_VALUE output in SQL server.

```
DECLARE @jsonString NVARCHAR(MAX) ='{"name":"jonh","address":"100 st \n city ,country"}'
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@jsonString,'$.address')
```

Output is "`100 st   city ,country`"

but I want output to be "`100 st \n city ,country`"

How to retain new line character.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the `\` in the json:

```
DECLARE @jsonString NVARCHAR(MAX) ='{"name":"jonh","address":"100 st \\n city ,country"}'
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@jsonString,'$.address')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is preserved, just SSMS converts it to a space when displaying in a table.
You can check it by converting to varbinary or by changing SSMS output to text:

```
DECLARE @jsonString NVARCHAR(MAX) ='{"name":"jonh","address":"\n100 st \n city ,country"}'

SELECT JSON_VALUE(@jsonString,'$.address'),cast(JSON_VALUE(@jsonString,'$.address') as varbinary(100))
```

You can use solution from [SSMS Results to Grid - CRLF not preserved in copy/paste - any better techniques?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679481/ssms-results-to-grid-crlf-not-preserved-in-copy-paste-any-better-techniques) to retain them in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach, using `STRING_ESCAPE()` with `'json'` as value for the `type` parameter:

Statement:

```
DECLARE @jsonString NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{"name":"jonh","address":"100 st \n city ,country"}'
SELECT STRING_ESCAPE(JSON_VALUE(JSON_QUERY(@jsonString), '$.address'), 'json')
```

Result:

```
100 st \n city ,country
```