# Insert a line break in a SQL Server not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

**example 1**

```
declare @text VARCHAR(100)
SET @text = 'this is the frist line' + CHAR(10)+CHAR(13) + 'Second line'
select @text
```

**example 2**

```
select 'This is line 1.' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 'This is line 2.'
```

why is not it working?
Not in the SQL management environment
And not through code in C#

Comment: CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057/how-to-insert-a-line-break-in-a-sql-server-varchar-nvarchar-string

Comment: I saw you write CHAR(14) which is clearly wrong

Comment: What does "not working" mean? How are you viewing these select results?

Comment: Are you sure it's not working, and not that you don't have retain the CR/LF feature turned off?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSMS Results to Grid - CRLF not preserved in copy/paste - any better techniques?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679481/ssms-results-to-grid-crlf-not-preserved-in-copy-paste-any-better-techniques)

Comment: Ah "Not in the SQL management environment" means that they are using SSMS but that it is not working there. Not that they are not using that environment!

Comment: Both your attempts work fine: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8a2af05625df3d85d1e2277934ea1ab3) Note that the first has *2* new lines, due to it being LF/CR *not* CR/LF.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on the output device.

So, if you use the standard grid output, then you get this:

[image]

but, if you change the output option from Grid to text, say this:

[image]

So, now your output is not to some grid control that can't displacy the cr+lf.

but, with text output to the sql console, then yes, we now get this:

[image]

Now you ALSO tagged this as asp.net?

So, what kind of control on the web page are you sending the markup to????

If you send the data to a standard asp.net text box - (hopefully set as mutli-line).

Then once again, it will correctly display the two lines.

But, if  you send that SAME text say to some "div" on the page as innerHTML, then the cr + lf will not work.

So, it comes down to like most things in life:

There is a important context here as to were you are sending the resulting data to.

Send such data to a console or text based output device (like the sql console - set as text), then it works. Sending to the built in SQL grid control? No, it does not work.

And same goes for sending such data to a web page. It will "depend" on what kind of control you use to render the data.

Answer (score -1):

I try to understand the question.
So, please, could you try to change/discover the Tools-Options-Quert Result-Result to Grid. To use the result to grid (more easy, just my opinion)
Could help you?

https://www.linkedin.com/posts/daniele-scordamaglia-460a78a5_sqlserver-sql-cr-activity-7053663883944701952-G8It?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop

[image]