# Retaining format of SQL statement when stored in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, sql-server-2016

We store several sql statements in one of our tables. For example, the following SQL statement will be stored in `[Validations].[SqlSource]`:

```
select 
VendorId,
VendorName,
VendorAddress,
VendorCity,
VendorState,
VendorZip
from Vendor
```

The problem is that when we copy this SQL directly from the table, it'll lose the carriage returns. This means that pasting the sql will look like this:

```
select VendorId, VendorName, VendorAddress, VendorCity, VendorState, VendorZip from Vendor
```

It's not an issue with this sql since it's short, but when the SQL is long, then the string when pasting will be long.

Is there a way to keep the formatting when I copy the string and paste to a text editor?

I added an example of how it's inserted into the table:

```
create table toerase_SQL
(
    SqlSource varchar(max)
)
insert into toerase_SQL 
select   
'select '+
'VendorId, '+
'VendorName, '+
'VendorAddress, '+
'VendorCity, '+
'VendorState, '+
'VendorZip '+
'from Vendor '

select * from toerase_SQL
```

Comment: Is `[Validations].[SqlSource]` of type `nvarchar(max)`?

Comment: It retains CRLF, see here https://dbfiddle.uk/iTyGx3Kx

Comment: What's the type of `SqlSource`? What tool are you using to store and retrieve the data?

Comment: SQL will preserve line breaks.  Most likely the issue you're seeing is down to the tool you're using to view/copy the value.  From your tags it looks like you're using SSMS; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37284582/361842

Comment: I added DML on how the sql is inserted.

Comment: Have you tried putting a line-break in your inserts to see if it's preserved? e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/Fqi3QtZ1

Comment: @EdmCoff: I haven't tested it, but I'm pretty sure it'll work. The problem is that it would involve another step, aside from adding the single quotes.

Comment: You don't have to write out the CRLF explicitly. As a previous comment shows (and my second example shows) you can just not close your string so that the line-breaks are actually part of it

Comment: how do you copy it? it seems the problem is related to usage of SSMS or similar clients

Answer (score 3):

When you concatenate strings with something like

```
SELECT
'a' +
'b' +
'c'
```

it means, take the string 'a' and append the string 'b' and then append the string 'c', so the result is 'abc'. It does not automatically add line-breaks (nor spaces) that happen to be near the plus/concatenation operator.

It is the same as

```
SELECT
'a'+'b'+'c'
```

You will need to include the line-breaks in the string in order to select them.

For example,

```
SELECT
'a
b
c'
```

has the line-breaks captured within the string itself.

Or you could add line-breaks explicitly, like

```
SELECT
'a' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
'b' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+
'c'
```

You can see both of these methods [working in this Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Fqi3QtZ1).