# How to Add New Column in Existing Table Value Parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008, table-valued-parameters

I have a TVP like below:

```
CREATE TYPE TestTableType AS TABLE
 (
    Id INT,
    AnswerId INT
 );
```

In this TVP I want to Add one more column **AnswerText**, How to do that without drop TVP (I did not have permission to drop TVP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx it states: You cannot use ALTER TABLE statements to modify the design of table-valued parameters.

Also see [How to ALTER the Table Value Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734541/how-to-alter-the-table-value-parameter) for good way to modify it without downtime by creating a new TVP and using it temporarily while you drop and recreate the original TVP.