# SQL list of all the user defined functions in a database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am looking for a SQL query that outputs the function definitions for all of the user defined functions in a database catalog.

I have found as far as

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.UserFunctionName')) AS [Object Definition]
```

and

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME FROM information_schema.routines WHERE routine_type = 'function'
```

but I can't think of or find a way to feed the ROUTINE_NAME list to the OBJECT_ID.

The purpose here is a searchable text of the user defined function definitions in a database for database change analysis, if something like a full SQL procedure or purposed helper program is easier, I will do that and post it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I list user defined types in a SQL Server database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54482/how-do-i-list-user-defined-types-in-a-sql-server-database)

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk this is not a duplicate of that question at all. this is looking for udf's and their definitions, not udt's...

Answer (score 101, accepted):

```
SELECT o.name, m.definition, o.type_desc 
  FROM sys.sql_modules m 
INNER JOIN sys.objects o 
        ON m.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE o.type_desc like '%function%'
```

Comment: This answer is better for allowing easier inclusion of other columns of info if needed.  Geoff's CTE also fits the bill great, I think the CTEs are a useful technique I wish I had known for other situations.  Knowing about sys.sql_modules and its object_id key reference, from RandomUs1r, an IN(SELECT SUBQUERY) was best for my purposes.

Answer (score 9):

You could use a CTE:

```
with functions(routine_name) as 
  (SELECT ROUTINE_NAME FROM information_schema.routines WHERE routine_type = 'function')
select 
  OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(routine_name)) AS [Object Definition] 
from 
  functions
```

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT O.name, M.definition, O.type_desc, O.type
FROM sys.sql_modules M
INNER JOIN sys.objects O ON M.object_id=O.object_id
WHERE O.type IN ('IF','TF','FN')
```

Comment: Hi tinamou,
Here, we are fetching function's name, definition and Type of user defined function.

user defined function can be Inline function(IF) or Scalar function(FN) or table valued function(TF).

Answer (score 5):

Similar to this solution:  [Query to list all stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219434/query-to-list-all-stored-procedures)

```
SELECT * 
  FROM DIDS0100.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
 WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'FUNCTION' 
    AND LEFT(ROUTINE_NAME, 3) NOT IN ('fn_')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version that includes schema, and is formatted to allow the mass-dropping of un-needed scalar-valued functions:

```
SELECT ('DROP FUNCTION [' + SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) + '].[' + o.name + ']') AS ObjectName 
FROM sys.sql_modules m INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id = o.object_id 
WHERE o.type_desc = 'SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION' 
ORDER BY ObjectName
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate a parameter list for all SQL Server stored procedures and functions

```
SELECT 
   SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID) AS [Schema]
  ,SO.name AS [ObjectName]             
  ,SO.Type_Desc AS [ObjectType (UDF/SP)]
  ,P.parameter_id AS [ParameterID]
  ,P.name AS [ParameterName]
  ,TYPE_NAME(P.user_type_id) AS [ParameterDataType]
  ,P.max_length AS [ParameterMaxBytes]
  ,P.is_output AS [IsOutPutParameter]
FROM sys.objects AS SO
INNER JOIN sys.parameters AS P ON SO.OBJECT_ID = P.OBJECT_ID
ORDER BY [Schema], SO.name, P.parameter_id
```