# Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.GetUserBranchIDs", or the name is ambiguous

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

The function is a scalar function that returns `nvarchar(1000)`, and I'm calling it from LINQ to SQL:

```
var allUserBranchIDs = appContext.DataContext.GetUserBranchIDs(appContext.PersonID, branchDelimiter);
```

And it gives this error:

> Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.GetUserBranchIDs", or the name is ambiguous

It runs just fine when I call it from SQL Server Management Studio:

```
select [dbo].[GetUserBranchIDs](3678, ',')
```

Which suggests a permissions issue with the SQL user that the DataContext is using - but I'm using the exact same `sa` user in LINQ to SQL that I am in SSMS!

edit: here is the LINQ to SQL generated method:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.GetUserBranchIDs", IsComposable=true)]
public string GetUserBranchIDs([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="UserID", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> userID, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="Delimiter", DbType="NVarChar(10)")] string delimiter)
{
    return ((string)(this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), userID, delimiter).ReturnValue));
}
```

edit: function definition:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetUserBranchIDs] 
(
    @UserID int,
    @Delimiter nvarchar(10) = '/'
)
RETURNS nvarchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN

    declare @result nvarchar(1000) = null;

    select @result = coalesce(@result, '') + cast(a.BranchID as nvarchar(10)) + @Delimiter
    from (
        select distinct  
            b.BranchID      
        from vw_UserBranchCurrent a
        inner join vw_BranchDataCurrent b
            on a.BranchID = b.BranchID
        where
            ((@UserID is not null) and (a.UserID = @UserID))
    ) a;

    set @result = left(@result, len(@result) - len(@Delimiter));

    return @result;

END
```

Comment: That TSQL query looks like a scalar-valued UDF, but your LINQ call looks like it's expecting a table-valued UDF.

Comment: What result do you get when you run your code in SSMS?

Comment: It's not a permissions issue. Your error message would be much different if that were the case.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft hmm, I just dragged the function from Server Explorer into my DBML file; I've used other scalar valued functions in the past with no problems - how do I need to change the LINQ call for a scalar valued function?

Comment: @Brian I get a list of branch IDs separated by my specified delimiter, e.g. "1,3,4,5"

Comment: I have no idea, as I haven't used L2S in a very long time. What does the C codegen for the function look like?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I added the generated LINQ to SQL method to my question. Thanks!

Comment: @ekolis do you get a scalar string value or do you get a table with a single row where that row is a single `VarChar` column?  It makes a difference.  It might be helpful if you updated your question to include the definition of `GetUserBranchIDs()`.

Comment: @Brian How would I tell the difference between a single cell table and a scalar result? I'll go ahead and add the definition of the function.

Comment: @ekolis this line in the function definition tells you that it returns a scalar:  `RETURNS nvarchar(1000)`

Comment: @Brian Oh, of course! So do you know what I'd need to change to prevent the error I'm seeing, now that you have the definition of the function?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I am a complete idiot... I thought I was using one database but I was actually using another (we have a separate database per client in each of three environments: dev/test/prod). That's why the function was missing - I had added it to the wrong database!

Comment: I think you should [edit] your answer and indicate that you are answering your own question.

Comment: Is that the standard etiquette around here? I wasn't aware of that....

Answer (score 2):

I was going to say to check which current DB Catalog your are using in your script vs what catalog you are using in Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS).

```
select DB_NAME()
```

Then once you know the current database you could create another script to confirm which user defined functions are available for that catalog using something like this post but with a modification to allow for function name matching:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15420524/2256278

```
DECLARE @yourFunctionGuessValue nvarchar(200) = 'someFunctionNamePart'
SELECT name, definition, type_desc 
FROM sys.sql_modules m 
INNER JOIN sys.objects o 
    ON m.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE type_desc LIKE '%function%'
and name LIKE '%' + @yourFunctionGuessValue + '%'
```

Hope this helps.