# What is the true sys.all_objects?

Tags: sql-server, system-views

I am working with `SQL Server 2008 R2` and `SQL Server 2016`.

I have bunch of `User-Defined Data Types` but they dont show in `sys.all_objects`. What is the true catalog view which can return all user-defined objects?

Thanks

Comment: Types aren't *objects*. You'll find them in `sys.types`

Comment: agree but i am writing a query where I have to treat them as one for join purpose

Comment: In this case you'll have to change the query because they just aren't objects. You can't retrieve them from `sys.objects`. They don't have an OBJECT_ID. Change the query and query the correct table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I list user defined types in a SQL Server database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54482/how-do-i-list-user-defined-types-in-a-sql-server-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Types are not objects that would show up in the objects table. You can use the types table:

```
select * 
from sys.types
WHERE is_user_defined = 1
```

or you can use this bigger query from the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#d-returning-the-owner-of-each-object-in-a-schema) to return all your objects, types, and schema collections:

```
SELECT 'OBJECT' AS entity_type  
    ,USER_NAME(OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'OwnerId')) AS owner_name  
    ,name   
FROM sys.objects 
UNION   
SELECT 'TYPE' AS entity_type  
    ,USER_NAME(TYPEPROPERTY(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '.' + name, 'OwnerId')) AS owner_name  
    ,name   
FROM sys.types   
UNION  
SELECT 'XML SCHEMA COLLECTION' AS entity_type   
    ,COALESCE(USER_NAME(xsc.principal_id),USER_NAME(s.principal_id)) AS owner_name  
    ,xsc.name   
FROM sys.xml_schema_collections AS xsc JOIN sys.schemas AS s  
    ON s.schema_id = xsc.schema_id  

GO
```